# Stiefel classes and generic sections

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I asked this question in math.stackexchange few days ago.
Unfortunately, I haven't seen any simple answer.

One can say that the Stiefel-Whitney classes is dual classes to the locus of linearly dependence of generic sections. What means "generic"? I want to see some relation in local coordinates.

The same question about the Chern classes and a complex generic sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the vector fields (let say $r$ vector fields on an $n$ dimensional manifold $M$) as a map from the trivial $r$-dimensional vector bundle $\varepsilon^r$ over $M$ into the tangent bundle $TM.$
It gives a section $\alpha$ of the bundle $HOM(\varepsilon^r, TM).$ The fiber over $x \in M$ of this later bundle is the space of linear maps from $R^r$ to $T_xM = R^n.$  Let $\Sigma _x$ be the set of non-injective linear maps in the fiber over $x$, and let $\Sigma$ be the union of all $\Sigma_x$ as $x$ runs over the points of  $M.$
The set $\Sigma$ is a stratified subset in the total space $HOM(\varepsilon^r, TM)$. The vector fields are generic if the corresponding section $\alpha$ is transverse to $\Sigma.$